# Why do all my folders have ! or ? or a bomb sign on them after I installed rabbitvcs?

Tags: git, rabbitvcs

I recently installed rabbitvcs on an Ubuntu 17.10 machine.

After installing I am trying to clone one of my folders, but all my folders have an ! exclamation mark or ? question mark or a bomb sign after installing rabbitvcs. I have tried tortoise git in Windows but it didn't happen like this there.

I tried reinstalling rabbitvcs but the problem remains the same. And also the all the folders have those signs outside the folder which I am trying to clone.

Is rabbitvcs is the best alternative for tortoise git in Ubuntu for the latest Ubuntu version?

[image: directories with ! Symbol]

What is the fix for this problem? Is there any good documentation for rabbitvcs?

Comment: This sounds likely to be a bug in rabbitvcs.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen how will you justify the ! or ? sign on all of the folders in ubuntu outside the folder which I am trying to clone

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen by the way I have already followed that link but no help

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution found [here](http://opentechlabs.blogspot.com.ng/2015/05/svn-bomb-sign-ubuntu-solution.html):

1. Kill the `checkerservice.py` Process under rabbitvcs
2. Run `ps aux | grep rabbitvcs`
3. Use command `kill -9 <process_id_of_checkerservice.py>`
4. Restart the Nautilus and the solution worked.